# how would you add span element after each input except last input

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dom, ecmascript-6

I have tried this since all input has one parent, This adds at last element; if i do that with outerHtml that breaks the next focus

```js
const inputArr = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input'));
const span = document.createElement('span');
const text = document.createTextNode('-');
span.appendChild(text);
for (let input of inputArr) {
  console.log(input.parentElement);
  input.parentElement.insertBefore(span, input.nextElementSibling)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-otp-input, I am using this package where i would like to add span element after each input except last one.

Current output:

[image]

Required Output:

[image]

Comment: Any given element, like the `<span>` your code creates, can only appear at one place in the DOM.

Comment: No if you see my code there is an for loop that can be used to append after each input element, But it is not working as per required

Comment: I see the `for` loop. You did not understand my comment: you only create **one** `<span>` element. It can only appear at one place in the DOM. Your code is trying to add it to many different places, and that will not work.

Comment: got it, I thought once you create any element, you can insert as many times, Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add the same element twice in your loop. You should create a new one for each iteration. Also, if you use a regular `for` loop rather than a *foreach*, you could loop from 0 to `inputArr.length - 1`. This way, you will not add `span` element to the last input.

```js
const inputArr = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input'));

for (let i = 0; i < inputArr.length - 1; i ++) {
  const span = document.createElement('span');
  const text = document.createTextNode('-');
  const input = inputArr[i];
  
  span.appendChild(text);
  console.log(input.parentElement);
  input.parentElement.insertBefore(span, input.nextElementSibling)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**P.S**
For a more clean way of acheiving this, I really like [Qurben's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63536622/5784924). It use the array functions correctly.

As a bonus, here is a almost *one line* of array function. Because who does not like complex lines of array functions ? /s

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input'))
  .filter((item, index, array) => index !== array.length - 1)
  .forEach(item => {
    item.parentElement.insertBefore(
        document.createElement('span')
        .appendChild(document.createTextNode('-')), item.nextElementSibling)
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.pop()` to remove the last element from your selected array. The creation of the span should also happen inside the array, because you want to have multiple spans.

```js
const inputArr = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input'));

inputArr.pop() // Remove the last element

for (let input of inputArr) {
  const span = document.createElement('span');
  const text = document.createTextNode(' - ');
  span.appendChild(text);
  console.log(input.parentElement);
  input.parentElement.insertBefore(span, input.nextElementSibling)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

You can also use `.slice(0, -1)` (select from zero until the last element). This method does not change the underlying array. The for loop would the be something like the following. (With the `.pop()` call removed)

```
for (let input of inputArr.slice(0, -1))
```